# If $G$ is triangle-free does that imply it is a complete bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory, triangles, bipartite-graphs

If $G$ is triangle-free does that imply it is a complete bipartite graph?

I know every bipartite graph is triangle free, and any complete bipartite graph has no triangles but does a graph being triangle free imply it's a complete bipartite graph? Also, are the independent sets in the triangle free graph (if the above is true) equal?

Comment: Try thinking about cycles longer than $3$ or $4$.

Comment: Right, $C_6$ is triangle free and bipartite, but is not complete bipartite. You can put that as an answer, and I'll award it as the answer.

Comment: If a better answer appears however, I’ll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivially no. If you remove edges from a triangle-free graph then you get another triangle-free graph, whereas if you remove edges from a complete bipartite graph you get a graph which is bipartite but not complete. Therefore this could only be the case if all triangle-free graphs were edgeless.

Comment: Is this related to the isomorphism classes of triangle free graphs and complete bipartite graphs? I’m just trying to understand your answer which I intuitively understand more concretely.

Comment: I suppose you could relate it to them, but I'm not sure that it would be very useful. If you want to generalise, the key word is *hereditary*: being $G$-free for a given subgraph $G$ is subgraph-hereditary.

Answer (score 2):

Try thinking about cycles longer than $3$ or $4$. For example $C_5$ and $C_6$ are triangle free, but $C_5$ isn't even bipartite, and $C_6$ isn't complete bipartite.

Comment: I would also show what I said in the comments as an example such as $C_6$.